# How to ajax file upload fail with no error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check for the existence of a bunch of scripts. Currently I get this line a bunch of times in my console, which I would like to avoid:

`GET http://localhost:8888/js/flaw/blahblah.js 404 (Not Found)`

My current setup (i just added the try catch thing as an attempt, but it did not work.)

```
var filesThatExist = [];
var filesThatDont = [];

function loadScript(path) {
  try {
    $.ajax(path)
      .done(function(){
        filesThatExist.push(path);                                       
      })
      .fail(function(){
        filesThatDont.push(path);
      });
  } catch (e) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid it by having your server check the existence rather than javascript.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why not? your server can check the existence even if it doesn't live on that server. your server can perform the same http request that that ajax request is making.

Comment: @KevinB No, that is not my question, but thanks for the tip, maybe what i want is not possible :(

Comment: you can't hide the 404 warning other than not causing it to happen in the first place. That's the basis of my previous comments.

Comment: @KevinB well, i suppose if your sure, then you can add that as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those aren't javascript errors, there isn't anything you can do to avoid it aside from not sending an ajax request to something that doesn't exist.

Best alternative would be to have a service on your server that loops through the urls checking for existence.

Comment: The 404s do appear in the errors tab of the chrome console, not the warnings tab...